# How do i change my links from samplesite.com/pages?id=firstList to samplesite.com/pages/firstList

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have created a html page(pages) and showing different content there according to the **'id' fetched from database(='fistList')**. therefore in order to navigate to that page i am using href as something like this:

```
<div class="odd-item" onclick="location.href='<?php echo get_the_permalink(18).'?id='.$row->id; ?>';">
```

where **get_the_permalink(18)** corresponds to the **samplesite.com/pages**.

what i want to do is change my links **from samplesite.com/pages?id=firstList to samplesite.com/pages/frstList or samplesite.com/pages?id=firstList to samplesite.com/pages?id=scondList** and so on...

Thanks.

Comment: If you use WordPress, you can change it from setting and permalinks

Answer (score 0):

Try with the Permalink Settings in the WordPress admin dashboard.

Go to the Permalink Settings and select "Post name" or can use a custom structure, and "Save changes".

Comment: I'm not using different posts, I'm just using a single page i.e. get_the_permalink(18) or samplesite.com/pages and displaying different content on this same page by fetching 'id' 
 and showing different content on this same page.

Comment: These permalink settings will work for posts and pages both.

Comment: but I'm not using different pages, its just one page and different content displayed on that page based on the id fetched from databasae, for e.g. if id=firstPage then different content is displayed.